# Trouble converting from JSON to C# objects - how do the classes work?

Tags: c#, json, object

```
{
 "device": "Lamp",
 "type": "Switch",
 "commands": [
  {
   "name": "turn Lamp on",
   "command": "/api/Lamp/ON"
  },
  {
   "name": "turn Lamp off",
   "command": "/api/Lamp/OFF"
  }
 ]  
}
```

I need to deserialize the JSON into a(n) C# object(s). I am having trouble though understanding how to format the C# code. I used [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) and came up with this:

```
 public class Command
 {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string command { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
 {
  public string device { get; set; }
  public string type { get; set; }
  public List<Command> commands { get; set; }
 }
```

However, I do not fully understand the two different objects. This is the C# code that returns a null value for `command1`:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = "http://localhost:8080/api/whatcanisay/";
string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

Commands command1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Commands>(json);
TestOutput.Text = command1.command;
```

If someone could explain the classes and how they transfer over from the JSON, that would be really helpful.

Comment: What *exactly* do you not understand? Your question is too vague at the moment. (It doesn't help that your code talks about `Commands` as a type, and that isn't one of the types you've shown us. I suspect you want `RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`.

Comment: Do `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)` and go from there.

Comment: @JonSkeet, as I stated above, I do not understand how the JSON data is transferred into C# classes.

Comment: @Morgan4568771: You would use `root.commands`. At this point it's not really clear whether you don't understand the JSON conversion, or whether you don't understand the C# classes - in which case I would *strongly* suggest that you learn about the core concepts of C# before going any further.

Comment: So why would you not understand how to get from a `RootObject` to the commands? At that point it doesn't have anything to do with JSON... you've got a reference to a `RootObject`, so you use it like you would any other `RootObject` you'd created...

Comment: I've got that part. I don't understand how the JSON is divided into two classes, Command and RootObject.

Comment: @Morgan4568771 take a look at your json, `command` contains an array of objects so the equivalent in C# would be `List<Command> commands`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSON.net which is one of the most popular JSON framework for .NET.

Basically the way it works you define classes that matches the JSON schema, and then it turns the json string into C# objects.

The purpose is it makes it easier to parse the JSON data otherwise you would have to map each JSON values to your object properties manually.

It is an open source project, so feel free to read the code

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your JSON string using the Microsoft **System.Web.Extensions** and [JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

First, you must have classes associated to your JSON file. To create classes, select your JSON sample data and, in Visual Studio, go to **Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON As Classes**.

Next, use this sample.

```
string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
var root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
// root object contains all JSON data.
```

Or you can also use a full JSON Library like http://www.newtonsoft.com/json